# Setup project custom action cancelation

Tags: .net, setup-project

I need to cancel/rollbak msi uninstallation made by Setup Project in Visual Studio 2008.

this is the script i execute as Uninstall Custom Action

```
set service = GetObject ("winmgmts:")
for each Process in Service.InstancesOf ("Win32_Process")
    If Process.Name = "App.exe" then
        Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        intButton = WshShell.Popup("App is running, you cannot uninstall it", 0, "Uninstall error", 0)
    End If
next
```

it shows the message when process is running but after i click "OK" uninstallation continues when i want to rollback/cancel it.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you throw an exception?

I'm struggling to remember but I think I once wrote some uninstaller code that did this (accidentally, but fortunately in a Dev environment!) and had a heck of a job trying to get the app uninstalled (because it kept rolling back the uninstall when it hit the exception).

Comment: lol ! i get you so much. Probably next step is to move Installer to WiX

Comment: yeah, wix certainly takes you that much closer to the core setup api. Its been a constant frustration that in their aim to make building setup programs "simple", these setup projects prevent you from doing so much. Possibly that's why they gave up for VS2012? Ironically the setup api itself is very functional, just difficult.